# Decreasing Google App Engine deploy time?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, flask, google-cloud-platform

I have deployed a Flask app on Google App Engine. The app works great, but every time I make an update, I run `gcloud app deploy` and the `Updating service [default]...` block takes forever. Sometimes as long as 10 minutes. My app is relatively simple and I have gigabit WiFi, so I'm not sure why it's taking so long.

Is there any way to optimize this?

Requested edits:

The main function of the app is to process a text message received via Twilio and return data from a Google Sheet.

app.yaml:

```
runtime: python39
entrypoint: gunicorn -b :$PORT main:app
```

requirements.txt:

```
Flask==0.12.3
google-api-core==1.26.1
google-api-python-client==2.0.2
google-auth==1.28.0
google-auth-httplib2==0.1.0
google-auth-oauthlib==0.4.3
googleapis-common-protos==1.53.0
requests==2.25.1
requests-oauthlib==1.3.0
gunicorn==19.7.1
twilio==6.53.0
```

Terminal output after initial `gcloud app deploy`:

```
Beginning deployment of service [default]...
#============================================================#
#= Uploading 5 files to Google Cloud Storage                =#
#============================================================#
File upload done.
Updating service [default]...done.
```

Comment: Do you use Flex or standard  version of App Engine? Can you share your app.yaml file?

Comment: Do you know how many files are being uploaded (check your deploy output and look for the line that says - Uploading XXXXX files to Google Cloud Storage)? If it's large, see if there are files that can be dropped for example the ```app.yaml``` has a ```skip_files``` block where you can specify files not to be uploaded. These would include .pyc files (if your app is in Python)

Comment: 10 minutes is not a long time to deploy a service. Your question lacks details on what you are deploying, therefore we can only guess and offer suggestions. Edit your question with details (deployment files, deploy command output) so that we can see what you are deploying.

Comment: Please see my edits. Hopefully it provides good context. I'm using app engine standard, and have a .gcloudignore to omit my venv directory and .pyc files.

Comment: Based upon your edit, I do not see anything to optimize that would reduce the time to deploy a new service. What you are experiencing is normal.

Comment: Huh. I guess I just figured it would be faster, given that sometimes I literally only need to change small bits of syntax and redeploy. I test it on my local machine and it runs just fine, but GAE often gives me new errors, so fixing one small error ends up taking 20 mins.

Comment: I still think that his is quite normal time. If you think the time is abnormal indeed and this is reproducible issue you should raise it on [Public Issue Tracker](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/community) or using [Submit Product Issue](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/support)